# Trying to install Python virtualenv on windows 10.

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Getting an error. I already have Python 3.6.3 running properly and I see pip, pip3 and pip3.6 in my scripts directory. I type "C>\pip3 install virtualenv" and it starts, "collecting virutalenv ... installing collected packages" but then "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied...   What am  I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/#installing-packages-using-pip-and-virtualenv), you should specify the user for which you're trying to install virtualenv.

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

Unless if you're logged in as the Administrator.